# Exception when trying to close a form with invoke

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I'm developing an application where I use OAuth 2.0, in the main thread I call the OAuth2 form like this

```
OAuth2.ShowDialog(Me) = DialogResult.OK
```

and I check its return, the reason for using ShowDialog is to lock the parent UI until the user authenticates, now the problem happens inside the OAuth2 form, I'm using CefSharp to create a web browser on Load event, then I handle URL changes to check if the URL matches and I can get new access tokens, the only way this function should fail is if on browser creation it entered the if and tried to close before the shown event, but I tested it and it never happens, for the URL to match the user has to interact with the browser and log in

```
Imports CefSharp.WinForms
Public Class OAuth2
    Private WithEvents Browser As ChromiumWebBrowser

    Private Sub OAuth2_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Me.InitializeComponent()
        Dim settings As New CefSettings()
        If Not CefSharp.Cef.IsInitialized Then
            CefSharp.Cef.Initialize(settings)
        End If

        Browser = New ChromiumWebBrowser(URL) With {
            .Dock = DockStyle.Fill
        }
        Me.Controls.Add(Browser)

        Me.Text = "OAuth2"
    End Sub

    Private Sub UrlChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Browser.AddressChanged
        If Browser.Address.Contains("example") Then
            'updates some variables
            'update a text file

            '########

            'Me.Invoke(Sub() Me.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK)    
            'OK()
            'OK2()

            '########

        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub OK2()
        Me.Invoke(Sub() Me.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK)
    End Sub

    Private Sub OK()
        If Me.InvokeRequired Then
            Me.Invoke(New MethodInvoker(AddressOf OK))
            Exit Sub
        End If
        Me.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK
        Me.Close()
    End Sub

End Class
```

I searched a lot to try and find the problem and found a solution, but I don't understand the difference between what I did and why it works if I do it differently

A) `Me.Invoke(Sub() Me.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK)`

if I use this to close and report an OK result it throws an exception `System.InvalidOperationException: Invoke or BeginInvoke cannot be called on a control until the window handle has been created` but not always.

B) `OK() or OK2()`

if I call any of these functions it works 100% of the time, with no exceptions.

I found the OK() snippet and from what I understand it checks if invoke is required, which in this case will always be true since I'm only calling it from a non UI thread, and then invokes itself I think? Then since invoke is always required I tried creating OK2() that invokes without checking anything and it also works. I don't understand the difference between trying to invoke directly and calling OK2() that does the same thing. What am I missing? Should I close this form differently?

Comment: Calling Me.InitializeComponent() in the Load event is quite wrong.  Belongs in the constructor (Sub New), that was already done.  So if you had the browser on the design surface then the UrlChanged event may fire early, before the Load event and tripping this exception.

Comment: I'll change that, but the exception is only throwing after the user interacts with the browser UI, everything runs ok and I try to close the dialog returning status OK.